# Custom REST Resource POST problem

Tags: 8

I want to POST json data to a custom REST resource. I tested with postman and Insomnia but i get the message as if would've done a GET request and returns the get functions result. The GET function works fine btw.

In the logs it says "Switched from post to get".

I just want to return the data the user passes. This is the code of my custom REST resource:

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\foolzz_rest_api\Plugin\rest\resource;


use Drupal\rest\Plugin\ResourceBase;
use Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse;

/**
 * Provides User Profile REST Resource
 *
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "profile_resource",
 *   label = @Translation("Profile resource"),
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/foolzz_rest_api/profile/{uid}"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class ProfileResource extends ResourceBase
{
    /**
     * Responds to entity GET requests.
     * @return \Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse
     */
    public function get($uid = NULL)
    {
        $query = \Drupal::database()->select('foolzz_users_profile', 'data');
        $query->fields('data', array('fk_users_uid','status','displayname','birthdate','biography','gender','realname'));
        $query->condition('data.fk_users_uid', $uid);

        $profile = $query->execute()->fetchAssoc();

        $response = ['profile' => $profile
        ];

        $build = array(
            '#cache' => array(
                'max-age' => 0,
            ),
        );

        return (new ResourceResponse($response))->addCacheableDependency($build);
    }

    /**
     * Responds to POST requests.
     * @return \Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse
     * Returns a list of bundles for specified entity.
     *
     * @throws \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException
     *   Throws exception expected.
     */
    public function post(array $data = []) {

        $response = array(
            "data" => $data,
        );

        $build = array(
            '#cache' => array(
                'max-age' => 0,
            ),
        );

        return (new ResourceResponse($response))->addCacheableDependency($build);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you've stumbled across the same stumbling block as I have a couple of times. Try with this piece of code - note the create entry after canonical:

```
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/foolzz_rest_api/profile/{uid}",
 *     "https://www.drupal.org/link-relations/create" = "/foolzz_rest_api/profile/{uid}"
 *   }
 * )
```

Read more at: 
https://www.drupal.org/node/2811757
and
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/restful-web-services-api/restful-web-services-api-overview

Oh and for the post request, I'd use [`ModifiedResourceResponse`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21rest%21src%21ModifiedResourceResponse.php/class/ModifiedResourceResponse/8.4.x) instead of fiddling with cache headers by hand (I learned about the existence of that from Drupal Core's [`EntityResource`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21rest%21src%21Plugin%21rest%21resource%21EntityResource.php/class/EntityResource/8.4.x))

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I use this second line of uri_paths by myself in an extra rest resource which I'm only using to post data, because when I have these 2 lines in my resource with `GET` and `POST` then i receive this error : `{
  "message": "No route found for \"POST /foolzz_rest_api/profile/1\": Method Not Allowed (Allow: GET, HEAD)"
}`

Comment: Hi! Have you remembered to enable POST for your endpoint at `/admin/config/services/rest` (if you use the Rest UI module)?

Comment: Sure. Post is enabled.

Comment: Right, so you have 1. the two urls defined AND 2. post allowed for that rest endpoint AND 3. you have granted permission for the role in question to post to this endpoint? Hmmmm scratching my head here.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the syntax for your uri_paths annotation should be:

```
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/foolzz_rest_api/profile/{uid}"
 *     "https://www.drupal.org/link-relations/create" = "/foolzz_rest_api/profile"
 *   }
```

The {uid} is not needed on the second line as it is present in the canonical path.

Comment: Dont forget to add comma after route definition `"canonical" = "/foolzz_rest_api/profile/{uid}",`, if you skip then you will get `Fixing an error: Expected Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocLexer::T_CLOSE_CURLY_BRACES `